# rewrite rule to send any url to index.htm?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I positively suck at understanding rewrite rules. I did  look over a bunch of docs but I keep getting 404 error.

I figured

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.htm
```

Will send any url to `index.htm`, but I get 404 error when I try for example `www.hi.com/blah`.

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite enabled and working? Have you entered RewriteEngine On ? Maybe one of the other directives you have entered cause the server error, try removing them and leaving only the RewriteEngine On and you RewriteRule

Comment: yes, I tested this and it's working fine with some other expressions that I cut'n'pasted. But now that i try to write my own it fails. Because I have no idea what's going on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.htm$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.htm [R]
```

Comment: so you moved the slash from the pattern to the url I'm refreshing to? This produces a redirect loop since I'm now actually refreshing the page using the `[R]` and it's matching everything on the new load. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: modified answer to avoid redirect loop

Comment: that totally works. And thanks bunches. I replaced the `[R]` iwth `[L]` because I actually want to retain the original URL in the browser and use it in javascript. I hope that's the proper way of doing it?